# Click on app icon 5 times to start the app

Tags: android

The requirement is that the app should not start when the user taps/clicks on the app icon for first time. The user should tap/click on the app for 5 times, and then the app should start/launch.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not possible. You need to tweak the `OS` itself code to make this happens

Comment: Well @ShahriarNasimNafi you could just close the app the first 4 times surely? Then maybe some visual tweaking can be done to not make it look like it opened at all.

Comment: @ShahriarNasimNafi  i have seen this functionality in an android app somewhere. I am just unable to reproduce it by myself.

Comment: @HenryTwist Yes, may be. SharedPreferences for counting and if it smaller than 5, then close. And remain open and set the count 0 after equal 5.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to kill the process in onCreate

```
public class DefaultApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        //TODO: quick blocking save to local storage
        if(not 5 times opened){
           android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with an integer that is stored in `SharedPreference` and incremented each time the user launches the app until it becomes 5.

Use `finish()` in `onCreate` before the activity is displayed to the user.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        int value = prefs.getInt("COUNT", 0);
        if (value == 5)
             finish();
        else 
            prefs.edit().putInt("COUNT", value+1).apply();
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: My thinking was that this could cause a short flicker of the activity opening before closing. Hence why I put it in the`Application` `onCreate` instead. But perhaps visually it would not matter.

Comment: @EdwardvanRaak yeah `Application` would be early, and will work although getting shared preference in `Application` would be  [a challenge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43273774/how-to-getsharedpreferences-in-application) ..  As per my test, no flicker would appear as you finish the activity before `onResume()`